# How to see this improper integral diverges?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

$$\int^\infty_1\frac{1}{x^{1+1/x}}dx$$

I'm preparing for exams. I would also like to know what are some commonly used methods to show an improper integral diverges?

Comment: Look at $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} x^{1/x}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: good hint. Actually, all we really need is that $x^{1/x}\le e^{1/e}$.

Comment: True, @robjohn. But here, I think the limit is easier to find than the bound if one does not already know the bound.

Comment: @DanielFischer: that's true. I did say it was a good hint. I was just noting this because it would not require us to say, "for some $x$ large enough..."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\int_n^\infty\frac1{x^{1+1/x}}\,\mathrm{d}x
&\ge\int_n^\infty\frac1{x^{1+1/n}}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=nn^{-1/n}
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}nn^{-1/n}
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{-1/n}\\
&=\infty\cdot1
\end{align}
$$

---

Another approach is to notice that $x^{1/x}\le e^{1/e}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Consider the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{1+1/n}}$$

and apply the limit comparison test and the integral test.

Comment: Is the ratio test conclusive?

Comment: @robjohn Why not?

Comment: @user130916: the ratio of the terms tends to $1$, so the ratio test is inconclusive.

Comment: yuck i meant limit comparison test

Answer (score 0):

We can expand the denominator of the integrand

\begin{align}
&x^{1+1/x}=x x^{1/x}=x\exp \left( \frac{1}{x} \ln x \right)\\
=& x \cdot \left(1 + \frac{1}{x} \ln x + \frac{1}{2x^2} (\ln x)^2 + \cdots \right)\\
=& x+\ln x + \frac{1}{2x} (\ln x)^2 + O\left( \frac{(\ln x)^3}{x^2} \right) \\
=& O(x).
\end{align}

Therefore, the improper integral diverges.